# Sorting k-sorted arrays with a min heap

Tags: algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic

A good solution to sorting k-sorted arrays(each element is at most k away from its target position) is,

```
1) Create a Min Heap of size k+1 with first k+1 elements. This will take O(k) time. 

2) One by one remove min element from heap, put it in result array, and add a new element to heap from remaining elements.

overall complexity will be O(k) + O((n-k)*logK)
```

I can't understand the relevance of the array being k-sorted to using the heap technique. Won't this work even when the array is not k-sorted?

Comment: `[1, 2,  3, 0]`,  k=2

Comment: For completeness, above algorithm with @leventov's example results in `[1, 2, 0, 3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, this will not work when the array is not k-sorted.

Because the first element after sorting will always be the minimal elements among the first k+1 elements, and so on.

@leventov have shown us an example.

Answer (score 1):

**A : find k smallest numbers (not necessarily sorted) from an array:**
The method you think will work perfectly in `O(k) + O((n-k)*logK)` time  .

**B : sorting the array:**
you find the minimum number from the heap of size k at each step , but what if the minimum number from the array is situated at index k + 2 ?
You will not be able to get it placed in 1st step of your algorithm only , till the time you insert it you would have outputted 2 numbers arguing that they are `<` than the original minimum .

so , you definately want to have them to be displaced by `not more than k` from their sorted position .