# "Outer" sort of a partitioned array to k parts

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I guess this hasn't been asked again as I searched a lot for an answer.

I was studying k-sorted arrays (maximum k units far from correct position) for homework and I fully understsand that the opt solution is O(n*logk), using min heap etc. ([check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21087139/sorting-k-sorted-arrays-with-a-min-heap)).

Now I saw the following problem: Let's say you have an array A, which is partitioned in k parts. A1, A2, A3, ..., Ak. Without asking to get each and every of Ai sorted, you want to get every element of A1 be smaller than every element of A2 etc.

For example: A[2, 5, 3, 1, 5, 7, 10, 0] and k=2 then
A1 = [2, 3, 1, 0] and A2 = [5, 5, 7, 10]. The order of elements inside A1, A2 is totally indifferent but we care about every element of A1 be smaller than A2.

Well, it seems that the two problems are connected. Actually in the second problem we see that it's a "(k-1) sorted array", but we dont want to fully sort it like in the 1st problem, but create it instead from an totally unsorted array. Anyway, I 'have been thinking of the above the whole day. What would be your approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to this is to modify quick sort to terminate when the array to be sorted is short enough.

This should reduce the typical complexity to O(nlogk), but as is normal for quicksort it can still have O(n^2) worst case complexity.

Here is an example Python implementation to partition array A into k partitions:

```py
def qsort_block(arr, num, missing = 0):
    """Return array where max of each block is <= min of the next block.

    Each block should of length <num>, except the first is <missing> shorter.
    """
    if len(arr) <= num - missing:
        return arr
    below = [x for x in arr[1:] if x<arr[0]]
    above = [x for x in arr[1:] if x>=arr[0]]
    return qsort_block(below,num,missing) + [arr[0]] + qsort_block(above,num,(missing+len(below)+1) % num)

A = [2, 5, 3, 1, 5, 7, 10, 0]
k = 2
num = len(A)/k
print qsort_block(A,num)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 5, 7, 10]
 AAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBB
```

So all numbers in the A partition are less than those in the B partition.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should read about [K-select algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) based on partition.

Comment: I did so already. I posted this question because I saw that the solution's complexity is O(n*logk), otherwise there are several solutions.